# Compile and Run HelloWorld.java on linux

Tags: java, linux, shell, unix, powershell-3.0

I have created HelloWorld.java file in a linux folder. I would like to compile and run it. As I am doing it first time, and no such question posted here.
Below is the content of Java File:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello...How are you");
    }
}
```

I see Java is installed on the server. Below are commands and their output.

```
rakeshth@ldnserver000590 DEV $ ls
HelloWorld.java
rakeshth@ldnserver000590 DEV $ java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
rakeshth@ldnserver000590 DEV $ javac HelloWorld.java
-bash: javac: command not found
rakeshth@ldnserver000590 DEV $ java HelloWorld.java
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld.java
```

Please, let me know steps to compile and run this Java file.

Comment: looks like you only have the JRE installed

Comment: [Here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/linux/) you'll find a comprehensive tutorial about this.

Comment: @Java1 +1 thanks ! Please let me know what to do

Comment: sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-set-default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-bash: javac: command not found
```

It seems that your javac application is not in the PATH or it's missing.

First you should try to figure out whether you have installed a JRE or a JDK in your system.
**Java Runtime Environment (JRE) does not have the javac command**. You need to get familiar with the linux commands to find files and symbolic links. You should look for javac which should be under the **JDK_installation_folder/bin** ex. "/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/javac"

Example:

```
> whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /etc/java /usr/bin/X11/java /usr/local/java /usr/share/java
> readlink -f /usr/bin/java 
/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/bin/java
> ls /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/javac
/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/javac
```

Last line proves that javac is there . If you JDK is not installed download it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html). if it is you can compile your example like this example

```
> /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/javac HelloWorld.java
> ls HelloWorld.class 
HelloWorld.class
> java HelloWorld
Hello...How are you
```

If you want to put your javac in the path you could create a symbolic link to it. Example:

```
> sudo ln -s /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/javac /usr/bin/
```

If you want to put it in the path check out [this tutorial.](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/)

Comment: Thanks I am trying your solution.